# putting subversion online without http domain name

Tags: http, svn, ip, svn-checkout

I have a local repository that resides on my `computer_1`. I have setup my svn server using the following command:

```
svnserve -d -r Path_to_Repository
```

`computer_1` and `computer_2` are connected to each other through a router and can communicate with `ssh username@IP` command. Considering that `computer_1` does not have a registered domain name (e.g. `My_Domain.com`), can I create a new `working copy` on my `computer_2`? I would like to use the following command on `computer_2`:

```
svn checkout http://computer_1_IP_address  A_folder_on_computer_2 -m A_log_message
```

However, using other protocols other than `http` is ok, as long as I only need to have `computer_1_IP_address`

Answer (score 0):

You use `svnserve` and in this case the URL should have `svn://` protocol, not `http://`.

You should read the [documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.html) **before** beginning to configure the server!